# How does the Linux login work?

Tags: login, architecture, logind

I am wondering how the login actually works. It certainly is not part of the kernel, because I can set the login to use ldap for example, or keep using `/etc/passwd`; but the kernel certainly is able to use information from it to perform authentication and authorization activities.

There is also a systemd daemon, called logind which seems to start up the whole login mechanism.

Is there any design document I can look at, or can someone describe it here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `login` binary is pretty straightforward (in principle).  It's just a program that runs as `root` user (started, indirectly through `getty` or an X display manager, from `init`, the first user-space process).  It performs authentication of the logging-in user, and if that is successful, changes user (using one of the `setuid()` family of system calls), sets appropriate environment variables, umask, etc, and `exec()`s a login shell.

It may be instructive to read the source code, but if you do so, you'll find it easiest (assuming the standard `shadow-utils` login that Debian installs) to read it assuming `USE_PAM` is not set, at least until you are comfortable with its operation, or you'll find too much distraction.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/User-Authentication-HOWTO/) seems like a really good place to start. It has a discussion of `/etc/passwd` as well as PAM. I think you are really looking for a description of PAM. If you are looking to implement something for a  specific use, you can edit your question to give us an idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.